# Can Sodium atom (Na not Na+) be considered a free radical?

Tags: electrochemistry, radicals

By definition "Free radical is a chemical species that has a single unpaired electron in the outermost orbit". Sodium atom also has a unpaired electron in outermost shell and it is also highly reactive.

So, can it be considered a free radical and thus claiming that it can cause cell injury by oxidative damage?

Comment: Sodium almost always exists as Na+. The free metal does not exist in nature. [wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium?lang=en)

Comment: Sodium can reduce things, not oxidise, and there's absolutely no atomic sodium in any water solution.

Comment: Some radicals are strong oxidants, some strong reductants and some are not found in water solutions as there are no processes that would create them and keep them.

Comment: @zxen-xi, as you say, on Earth, sodium is almost always ionized... but "in nature" might be a bit to broad... after all, people are part of nature, and we *do* make metallic sodium, and it's relatively inexpensive, ~US$2/kg at https://www.made-in-china.com/products-search/hot-china-products/Wholesale_Pure_Sodium_Metal.html

Comment: But the context is biological matrix, where no atomic sodium occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure we can really consider metallic sodium in a bulk metal to be a free radical...

Answer (score 0):

Na atoms can be considered a radical but only in a context where they are stable. Possible situations are the gas phase, mercury amalgams, some metallic solutions, electrode reactions that do not involve water, possibly in liquid ammonia solution. Sodium atoms play no role in body biochemistry because it is waterbased and potentials are too low to reduce sodium ions to atoms.